# Can't set name and value at the same time in html input

Tags: php, html

I want to have date field in html which have default value of todays date, problem is that I can either set the value (through PHP) or set its name, never at the same time.

```
<input type="date" name ="dateInput" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" >
```

Thank you for answers

Comment: You have already set name hard coded `name ="dateInput"`

Comment: name of the input is hardcoded! use 
`<?php
$name = 'testName';
?>
<input type="date" name ="<?php echo $name;?>" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code on my server and it works fine. You can see the result by visiting http://phpfiddle.org/ and clicking the 'Code-Space' tab. Paste the following code in and click Run (F9).

`<input type="date" name="dateInput" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" >`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" name ="dateInput" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" >
```

The date should take the format `YYYY-MM-DD` . eg `value="2018-01-08"` ur

**UPDATE** :
Your Code is very fine , May be its browser issue use `type="text"` instant of `date` . Some browser doen't support HTML5 Date

```
<input type="text" name ="dateInput" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was probably because of the space before the equals, but now it works :D
Sorry for bothering you and thank you for your time trying to solve my problem